# Covariance matrix of a random variable and its affine transformation

Tags: random-variables, linear-transformations, covariance

Given:

- the random variable $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{c, \Gamma})$ where $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^L$
- its affine transformation $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} + \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{E}$ where , $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^D$, $\mathbf{E} \sim \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ and $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times L}$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^D$

I want compute the joint distribution of $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}$.
To do that, I am computing the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X}
\\ 
\mathbf{Y}
\end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N} \left( 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{c}
\\ 
\mathbf{A c + b}
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{\Gamma} &  \mathbf{R_{X,Y}}
\\ 
\mathbf{R_{Y,X}}  & \mathbf{\Sigma + A \Gamma} \mathbf{A}^T 
\end{bmatrix}
\right)$$

Where the I have computed the variance thanks to the properties of the affine transformations.
However I am having troubles on how to compute $\mathbf{R_{X,Y}}$ ( $ = \mathbf{R_{Y,X}}^T $).

Can someone help me? Or at least give some hint on solve using the following formula?

$$\mathbf{R_{X,Y}} = \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}])([\mathbf{Y} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Y}])^T]$$

I will need it to compute later the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ given $\mathbf{Y}$ using well know formulas (e.g. [conditional distribution of gaussian process](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html) )

Comment: What did you do finally?

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}} &= \text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}) = \text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, A\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{E}) \\
&=\text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, A\mathbf{X}) + \text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{b}) + \text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{E}) \\
&=\text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})A^\intercal + \mathbf{O} + \text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{E}) \\
&=\mathbf{\Gamma}A^\intercal + \text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{E})
\end{align*}
If $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ are known to be independent, then $\text{Cov}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{E}) = \mathbf{O}$ and we have $\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}} = \mathbf{\Gamma}A^\intercal$.

Answer (score 0):

First, say that all your vectors are $n\times1$. Hence $\mathbf{X}^{*}=(\mathbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}])$ is column and $\mathbf{Y}^{*T}=([\mathbf{Y} - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Y}])^T$ is row.

I guess that you ***would*** have no problem with computing the above. Basically, $\mathbf{X}^{*}$ as well as $\mathbf{Y}^{*T}$ are the mean-centered version of their "non-star" counterpart.

Then, one has $\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{X}^{*} \mathbf{Y}^{*T}$, which is a $n \times n$ matrix. Here as well, I guess that you ***would*** have no problem to compute this [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). *But*, what you must understand is that each of the $n^2$ components of $\mathbf{R_{X,Y}} = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Z}]$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{z}_{ij}]$ is actually rarely (not to say "not") computable as such, since it relies on the distribution of $\mathbf{z}_{ij}$. Yes, I am talking about the distribution of each $\mathbf{z}_{ij}$.

---

*One way* to get these $n^2$ distributions resorts to [resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29) methods. Those imply to repeat the calculation of $\mathbf{Z}$ many times, say, $m$ times.

Let's call $\mathbf{Z}_r$ for $r=1,...,m$, a counterpart of $\mathbf{Z}$, based on the $r$th of the $m$ resampled versions of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$, i.e. on $\mathbf{X}_r$ and $\mathbf{Y}_r$. Once you have the $m$ resampled versions of $\mathbf{Z}$, you can build the square matrix $\mathbf{R_{X,Y}} = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Z}]  = [m^{-1} \sum_{r=1}^m \mathbf{z}_{ij,r}]$.